# Checkbox com dependências

Tags: php, checkbox

No caso a quantidade e ilimitada de checkbox.

Ao marcar o checkbox é liberada uma linha com outros checkbox com a quantidade desejada desse ingrediente:

```
 Ingrediente               Quantidade

 [ ] Alface id#1           [X] 1x [ ] 2x [ ] 3x
 [X] Bacon id#2            [ ] 1x [ ] 2x [X] 3x
 [ ] Queijo Cheddar id#3   [X] 1x [ ] 2x [ ] 3x
 [X] Mostarda Dijon id#4   [ ] 1x [X] 2x [ ] 3x
```

.

```
Array
(
    [ingrediente_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
        )

    [quantidade_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
        )

)
```

Como eu faço para só salvar a quantidade_id que foi marcado pelo checkbox correspondente ao ingrediente_id?

os ingredientes que não foram marcados não poderá aparecer na array quantidade_id

Comment: Pelo php use a função `count()`

Comment: sim pelo php...

Comment: vou tentar com essa função

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para pegar a respectiva quantidade do ingrediente selecionado você pode passar o id do ingrediente no name de `quantidade_id` depois basta fazer um foreach para obter o ingrediente que será a chave do array e a quantidade que é o valor:

**[Exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dv41-3fys)**

form

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function habilitarQuantidade(item){

                var acao = true;
                if(item.checked === true) acao = false;

                for(var i = 1; i<=3; i++){
                    document.getElementById(item.value+'_'+i).disabled = acao;
                }

           }
        </script>
    </head>


<form action="" method="post">
    <?php
    $ingrediente = array(1 => 'Alface', 2 => 'Bacon', 3 => 'Queijo Cheddar', 4 => 'Mostarda Dijon');

    foreach($ingrediente as $id => $descricao){
        $checkbox = sprintf('
        <input type="checkbox" name="ingrediente[]" value="%d"  onclick="habilitarQuantidade(this);" /> %s
QTD: 1 <input type="checkbox" id="%d_1" name="quantidade_id[%d]" value="1" checked="checked" disabled="true"/>
     2 <input type="checkbox" id="%d_2" name="quantidade_id[%d]" value="2" disabled="true"/>
     3 <input type="checkbox" id="%d_3" name="quantidade_id[%d]" value="3" disabled="true"/>
<br>', $id, $descricao, $id, $id, $id, $id, $id, $id);

        echo $checkbox;
    }    
?>
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Arquivo php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['ingrediente'])){
    foreach($_POST['quantidade_id'] as $id_ingrediente => $qtd){
        echo 'ingrediente id: '. $id_ingrediente .' qtd: '. $qtd  .'<br>';
    }
}
```

O array recebido pelo é algo como:

```
Array
(
    [ingrediente] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 4
        )

    [quantidade_id] => Array
        (
                [1] => 1
                [4] => 3
id do ingrediente^     ^ quantidade 
        )

)
```

Comment: a quantidade_id teria que salvar o valor no array apenas se o ingrediente foi marcado...
no caso ta salvando 4 valores e não os 2 apenas que foi marcado

Comment: nesse caso ta retornando qual a profundidade desse array

Comment: Array
(
    [ingrediente_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
        )

    [quantidade_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

)
nesse caso o Bacon seria marcado com 2 e a Mostarda Dijon seria marcado com 3

Comment: pronto alterado

Comment: Lembre que é necessário usar javascript para habilitar/desabilitar os checkboxs de quantidade.

Comment: mais ai seria mesma coisa de pegar o valor do ingrediente_id e colocar ingrediente_id -1 pegaria o valor do campo quantidade_id correspondente... mais o array quantidade id ia ficar gigantesco.. sao mais de 50 itens

Comment: Array
(
    [ingrediente_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
        )

    [quantidade_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 2
        )

)

Comment: @Willian Só é enviado ao php os itens marcados.

Comment: a ta agora que vi

Comment: entao 
ingrediente id: 1 qtd: 1
ingrediente id: 2 qtd: 1
ingrediente id: 3 qtd: 1
ingrediente id: 4 qtd: 1
mesma coisa ta saindo todos... os ingredientes no array... pq o checkbox [1] 1x sempre vai ta marcado por causa do cliente... as vezes nao marca nao ver direito o que ta fazendo.. ai ja viu neh...

Comment: a quantidade sempre estará marca [X] 1x mais quem vai decidir se essa quantidade entra no array quantidade_id e o ingrediente, caso ele não esteja marcado a quantidade não entrar no array quantidade_id ficando assim apenas os ingredientes marcados com suas devidas quantidades

Comment: Obrigado @perdeu funcionou :D

Answer (score 1):

Você pode verificar com o `is(':checked')` do jquery qual quantidade foi selecionada e setar somente ela no seu array

```
for(){//percorrendo todos os ingredientes    
    if($("#input").is(':checked')){
        array[x][ingrediente] = $("ingredienteXX").val();
        array[x][ingrediente][quantidade]  = $("#input").val();
    }
    x++;
}
```

Não sei se essa seria a forma mais correta de se montar o array, mas assim no php vc poderia simplesmente pegar a quantidade especifica para cada ingrediente de acordo com o índice.

Comment: @peritto, não teria como com php

Comment: obrigado pela atenção :D