# Enviar Checkbox Selecionadas

Tags: php, html

Procurei em algumas perguntas aqui no site, mas não consegui entender bem. Eu tenho vários *checkboxes* como esse:

```
<td>
    <label class="ls-label-text">
        <input type="checkbox" name="adicional" value="L. Ninho" id="2.00">
        L. Ninho
    </label>
</td>
<td>
    <label class="ls-label-text">
        <input type="checkbox" name="adicional" value="Kit Kat" id="2.50">
        Kit Kat
    </label>
</td>
<td>
    <label class="ls-label-text">
        <input type="checkbox" name="adicional" value="Confete" id="2.00">
        Confete
    </label>
</td>
```

Dentro de um formulário, e eu envio esses dados para o banco de dados, só que quando eu envio, ele só envia um *checkbox*, ele não envia todos os selecionados.

O meu código do *action* é esse:

```
<?php
include "../../lib/inc_con.php";
session_start();
$mesa = $_POST['mesa'];
$tamanho = $_POST['tamanho'];
$quantidade = $_POST['qtd'];
$adicional = $_POST['adicional'];
$hiddentotal = $_POST['hiddentotal'];
$data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$produto_id1 = $_POST['produto_id1'];
$atendente_id = $_SESSION['id'];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pedidos (mesa, tamanho, qtd, adicional, hiddentotal, data, produto_id1, atendente_id) values ('$mesa', '$tamanho', '$quantidade', '$adicional', '$hiddentotal', '$data', '$produto_id1', '$atendente_id')") or die (mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: Oi Alfredo, você comentou do Action, mas esqueceu de postá-lo. Você poderia colocar como você está recuperando ele, por favor? A propósito, o browser submete todos os checkbox como o nome igual em um apenas, mas separados como se fossem um array. Poste o Action que eu lhe mostro como pegar certo nele.

Comment: Veja essa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82217/91) ou [essa outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32567/91)

Comment: Se você pode ter mais de um `adicional` por favor não  grave em uma coluna os valores separados por virgula, nada `implode/explode`. Já pensou em como vai consultar essa salada de frutas?

Comment: Dê uma lida aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql

Comment: Não somos um fórum :) http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/95582/revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mude o atributo `name` do seu checkbox para:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="adicional[]" value="Confete" id="2.00">
```

Assim o PHP vai receber um array de objetos, na hora de receber receba normal:

$_POST['adicional']

Dê um `var_dump` para entender como esses valores são recebidos.

Espero que ajude, abraços

Comment: Deu esse erro
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xamp\projects\MOClient 2.0\modulos\produtos\enviar.php on line 14

e aqui o var_dump
array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "L. Ninho" [1]=> string(6) "Pacoca" [2]=> string(13) "L. Condensado" }

e na linha 14 tem esse codigo

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pedidos (mesa, tamanho, qtd, adicional, hiddentotal, data, produto_id1, atendente_id) values

Comment: É uma lista de itens, quando salvar precisa fazer um laço e gravar um a um, de acordo como está seu banco de dados